# Get Currently Logged in username

Tags: vba, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to get the logged in username of the user by using VBS.

I tried some codes which works when I run the script directly (Double Clicking it)

```
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUser = wshNetwork.Username
WScript.Echo "Current User: " & strUser
```

However, what I need to do is to use CMD to run a scheduled task using the AT command.
When it ran, the username would be the computer's name instead of the logged in user.

This problem also occurs when I run CMD as administrator and use wscript to run the script.

Is there any way to bypass this context and get the logged in user instead of the one that runs the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
query session console
```

should provide what you need

For an easier to parse

```
quser console
```

EDITED - Included sample vbs code

```
Dim strCmd
    strCmd = "cmd /q /c ""quser console | find /i ""console"" "" "

Dim buffer 
    buffer = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(strCmd).StdOut.ReadAll()

Dim c, consoleUserName
    c = InStr(buffer,"console")
    If c > 2 Then
        consoleUserName = Trim(Mid(buffer,2,c-2))
    Else
        consoleUserName = ""
    End If

    WScript.Echo consoleUserName
```

Comment: thanks, I can see the user name, but how do I get the user name from the CMD console into the vbs script?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I used psexec to run wscript this sample code and it turns out blank

Comment: @BloopieBloops: change `WScript.Echo` with `WScript.StdOut.WriteLine` and run with cscript instead of wscript.

Comment: oh wait, i ran it with another method and it works! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you execute the command

set

from the prompt. It may reveal a few items that are set in the environment that may be of interest.

set user

will censor the list so that only variables that start `user` will be displayed.

Comment: How can i use this to make my vbs script display the logged in user? When in a session, set user displays administrator

Comment: Can't duplicate your observations. `USERNAME` is set correctly for me - running as administrator or not.