# Get Windows Login Name with JavaScript (running in Windows 10 Environment with CScript)

Tags: javascript, windows-10, wsh

I'm trying to create a custom Firefox deployment that generates homepage URLs by getting the First and Last Names of a Roaming Windows profile.

So far I have tried:

```
var wshell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
var username = wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
```

But this just keeps returning "Administrator". However, I am logged in under my name (an account with admin privileges). Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Currently Logged in username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985756/get-currently-logged-in-username)

Comment: Not JavaScript but exactly same issue as described above.